# A DFT analysis in a low speed data sampling

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, dft

I have some sample data of vibrations analysis from sensors installed on electrical motors. The sampling is made once or, at most, 3 times per day. The values can be expressed in `g`, `gE` or `mm/s`.

I’m developing a personal algorithm in JavaScript to process some samples and perform a DFT. It’s a simple code that uses brute force to process my results. I compared the results (real and imaginary parts) from JavaScript and from MATLAB results and they matched perfectly.

However, my sampling rate is very slow. Because of this, I have a lot of questions which I couldn’t find the answers on my searches:

1. Is it possible to apply a DFT analysis on a slow sampling data as this?
2. How can I determine the correct frequency scale for the X axis? It’s complicated for me because I don’t have an explicit Fs (sampling rate) value.
3. In my case, would it be interesting to apply some window function like Hanning Window (suitable for vibrations analyses)?

JavaScriptCode:

```
//Signal is a pure one-dimensional of real data (vibration values)
const fft = (signal) => {
    const pi2 = 6.2832 //pi const
    let inputLength = signal.length;
    let Xre = new Array(inputLength); //DFT real part
    let Xim = new Array(inputLength); //DFT imaginary part
    let P = new Array(inputLength); //Power of spectrum
    let M = new Array(inputLength); //Magnitude of spectrum
    let angle = 2 * Math.PI / inputLength;
    //Hann Window
    signal = signal.map((x, index) => {
        return x * 0.5 * (1 - Math.cos((2 * Math.PI * index) / (inputLength - 1)));
    });

    for (let k = 0; k < inputLength; ++k) { // For each output element

        Xre[k] = 0; Xim[k] = 0;

        for (let n = 0; n < inputLength; ++n) { // For each input element
            Xre[k] += signal[n] * Math.cos(angle * k * n);
            Xim[k] -= signal[n] * Math.sin(angle * k * n);
        }
        P[k] = Math.pow(Xre[k], 2) + Math.pow(Xim[k], 2);
        M[k] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Xre[k], 2) + Math.pow(Xim[k], 2));
    }
    return { Xre: Xre, Xim: Xim, P: P, M: M.slice(0, Math.round((inputLength / 2) + 1)) };
}
```

The first figure shows the charts results (time domain on the left side and frequency domain on the right side).

[image: DFT result]

The second figure shows a little bit of my data samples:

[image]

Obs.: I'm sorry for the writing. I'm still a beginner English student.

Answer (score 1):

1. The frequency doesn't matter. A frequency as low as 1/day is just as fine as any other frequency. But consider the Nyquist-Shannon theorem.
2. This is problematic. You need a fix sampling frequency for a DFT. You could do interpolation as preprocessing. But better would be to do the sampling at fix times.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I'm trouble... 
It’s impossible for me to set a sample time because the data is retrieved from an external system. Unfortunately, I don’t have access for change this. The collection structure belongs to SKF group.  I can only get the samples provided by SKF. There is a software where is possible to perform a DFT, but its usability is terrible. In this way, I would intend to build a new approach to process and show these data for the users.
Do you think there is a solution for me?
Would you like  to see some screenshots provided by SKF?

Comment: But you have the timestamps? You can use an approach similar to re-sampling. Choose a hypothetical higher sampling rate and map your real samples to the nearest sampling point of your hypothetical sampling. Maybe your actual samples occur at certain times, like always an a full hour. Sync your hypothetical sampling to that to keep the jitter low. Now you have oversampling with a missing values. Set them to 0 and low-pass filter your samples. (Cut-off frequency < 0.5/days, because your worst case is 1sample/day.) Take one sample/day and apply the DFT on that signal.

Comment: Hägar I’m a little confused. My knowledge about DSP (digital signal processing) is limited. I couldn understand completely your explanation. But I got that I need to rebuild the original signal with a fixed sample rate. I found a similar explanation here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8488/what-is-an-algorithm-to-re-sample-from-a-variable-rate-to-a-fixed-rate?noredirect=1&lq=1 
Although, I guess it’s a little complex. Please, could you be clearer? 
Should I use the sinc interpolation to retrieve my original signal? Thanks for your patience.